# Dalekjs: leave browser window open

Tags: dalekjs

I am new to using Dalekjs and am trying to open a browser, run some tests and (crucially) want to leave the browser window open.

Is there a way of doing this in Dalekjs? The default seems to be that the browser is automatically closed.

```
module.exports = {
'Page title is correct': function (test) {
  test
    .open('http://google.com')
    .assert.title().is('Google', 'It has title')
    .done();
}
};
```

I am running in a console using:

```
dalek my-test.js -b chrome
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the [`done`](https://github.com/dalekjs/dalek/blob/master/lib/dalek/unit.js#L165) function is run, it runs a promise with the result of your test and completes the test run - i.e. closing any running browser.

If you want to block a test and leave a window open, you will need to either use a [`wait`](http://dalekjs.com/docs/actions.html#meth-wait) to sleep for a given amount of time or a [`waitFor`](http://dalekjs.com/docs/actions.html#meth-waitFor) to wait until a given condition is met before the next step is processed.

I would suggest that you do something as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  'Page title is correct': function (test) {
    test
      .open('http://google.com')
      .assert.title().is('Google', 'It has title')
      .execute(function(){
        // Save any value from current browser context in global variable for later use
        var foo = window.document.getElementById(...).value;
        this.data('foo', foo);
      })
      .waitFor(function (aCheck) {
        // Access your second window from here and fetch dependency value
        var foo = test.data('foo');

        // Do something with foo...

        return window.myThing === aCheck;
      }, ['arg1', 'arg2'], 10000)
      .done();
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks Hady. I think I understand what you're doing here. However when I implement I get an error: 

`>> ERROR: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED`
`>> ERROR: Error: socket hang up`

Comment: If you can post your test in a fiddle maybe myself or others can try and help you further

Comment: Apologies, my bad. I was getting the error due to me not running the test properly. Running dalek name-of-test -b chrome instead of dalek name-of-test.js -b chrome.

Sorry your fix worked perfectly. Thanks Hady!